# Trying to update the joint table when the file is uploaded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure how do I update the joint table, Can someone help?

I have three tables students, classroom and a joint table classroom_students I should be able to upload a list of students in a CSV/Excel file and when the file is uploaded with students details I need to add the students to a classroom which means my joint table needs to be updated with the current classroom id and the new student ids which got added

I have used roo gem to upload the CSV/Excel file to update the

**classroom_student.rb**

```
belongs_to :classroom
belongs_to :student
```

**classroom.rb**

```
has_many :classroom_students
has_many :students, through: :classroom_students
```

**students.rb**

```
has_many :classroom_students
has_many :classrooms, through: :classroom_students
validates :student_fname, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }

def self.to_csv(options = {})
      desired_columns = ["id", "student_fname", "student_lname", "dob", "special_provisions", "gender", "aboriginal", "esl", "active"]
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
          csv << desired_columns
            all.each do |student|
            csv << student.attributes.values_at(*desired_columns)
          end
      end
    end

  def self.import(file, user_id)
      spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
        header = spreadsheet.row(1)
          (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
            row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
            student = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new 

            student.attributes = row.to_hash.merge(user_id: user_id)
            student.save!
          end
        end 
    end
```

**students_controller.rb**

```
def import
        @students = Student.all
      if params[:file].present?
        Student.import(params[:file], current_user.id)          
        redirect_to students_path, notice: 'Students imported.'
      else
        redirect_to students_path, notice: "You need to choose a file first!"
      end
  end
```

Comment: Can you perchance post the fields present on the import CSV?  I'm wondering how when importing you are expecting the classroom to get set

Comment: I have a form for creating a classroom and a link to upload the students (same page) to  to the classroom created so not sure should I update the students table and then update the joint table

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't need to touch the `classroom_students` table if you are just adding students to a classroom.  Rails should handle that automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails can actually automatically handle the classroom_students stuff for you.  For example, you might try something like this:

(Basically psuedocode)

```
# app/controllers/classrooms_controller.rb

def import_students
  @classroom.add_or_create_students_from_csv(csv)
end
```

.

```
# app/models/classroom.rb

def add_or_create_students_from_csv(csv)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(csv)
  header = spreadsheet.row[0]
  spreadsheet[1..-1].each do |row|
    # Find the student if they already exist (in this case by email), or create them if not.
    student = Student.find_or_initialize_by(email: row[header.index('email')])
    # Add the student to this classroom.  Rails is smart enough to handle the joins table automatically.
    self.students << student
    # If the student is being created, fill out the rest of the attributes from the spreadsheet
    if student.new_record?
      student.other_attribue_etc = row[header.index('other_attribute_etc')]
      # and so on
      student.save
    end
  end
  # Save the Classroom to create the associations
  self.save
end
```